# Limitations of database design with dynamic collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Can anybody, please, help me in understanding the limitations of designing dynamic collections with multiple databases in mongodb.

Currently, the design is such that, it has multiple databases like notifications, stats et al. and each time a new customer comes up, the customer will be assigned a new collection. Please help me with the limitations of this design esp. in terms of sharding this design.

Comment: Sharding in MongoDB takes place at the collection level.

Comment: @ZeMoon: If that collections get added to the databases dynamically, then will there be any problems while sharding?

Comment: AFAIK, sharding happens within collections. That means, the data within the collection is spread among the various shards available. To take advantage of sharding, you should keep all customers within the same collection, instead of creating new collections for each customer.